# Why can not I install nuget on VB.NET 2010?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, google-api-dotnet-client, google-custom-search

I am confused when installing nuget on VB.NET. I saw in the following tutorial how to install nuget on VB.NET 2010:

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/Using-Nuget-in-Visual-Studio-2010-&-2012

On the link, it is explained that I have to download nuget on the package manager. Then after that, restart VB.NET. On the link it is explained that after restarting VB.NET, I have to open menu - tools - select option - select package manager

In fact, after I follow the above, when I look for the option package manager, I did not find it. Then how the solution?

I also tried the tutorial on this link:

http://peterkellner.net/2011/03/02/installing-nuget-on-vs2010-first-blood/

And the result is the same. Package manager still not installed.

Screenshot 1 : 
[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkYzy.png)

Screenshot 2 :
[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybRvb.png)

Screenshot 3 : 
[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkKHp.png)

Comment: According to the 2nd guide it should appear under 'View' -> 'Other Windows' and not in the Options panel.

Comment: in 'view' - 'other window' is also nothing. I've included in the screenshot 3, you can see for yourself.

Comment: Looks like it may not be available to the Express version: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/05/21/no-extensions-for-visual-studio-express.aspx

Comment: Upgrade to VisualStudio 2015 or VisualStudio 2017.